# How can you access annotations on a field when generating LabelledGeneric?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is there a way to tag a generated shapeless `LabelledGeneric` with information about annotations on fields?

For example

```
case class Example(@someAnnotation foo: Foo, bar: Bar)
```

could we get something like

```
FieldType["foo" with Annotations(someAnnotation :: HNil), Foo] :: FieldType["bar", Bar] :: HNil
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have HLists `FieldType['foo, Foo] :: FieldType['bar, Bar] :: HNil` and `Some[someAnnotation] :: None.type :: HNil` using type classes `shapeless.LabelledGeneric`, `shapeless.Annotations`

```
implicitly[LabelledGeneric.Aux[Example,
  FieldType[Witness.`'foo`.T, Foo] :: FieldType[Witness.`'bar`.T, Bar] :: HNil]]

implicitly[Annotations.Aux[someAnnotation, Example,
  Some[someAnnotation] :: None.type :: HNil]]
```

Please notice that `'foo`, `'bar` (written as `` Witness.`'foo`.T ``, `` Witness.`'bar`.T `` for technical reasons) are singleton types that are subtypes of `Symbol`, not `String`.

If you really need an HList of intersections (`with`) or tuples `(fieldName, annotation)` then you can zip the HLists using one of type classes `shapeless.ops.hlist.Zip`, `shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipOne`, `shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipWith`.